# Where is the executable file for iOS and Xcode bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode

I only have the header and .m files and myApp.xcodeproj files but there is no "executable file" in my bundle? Can somebody tell where I can find it?

Comment: what's the file extension for your bundle?

Comment: You have source... have you built the project?

Comment: What are you looking for? The .app built from your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Organizer.  Select the Projects tab.  In the list on the left, select your project.  Click the little arrow to the right of the Derived Data path.  The folder should open in the Finder.  Open the subfolder whose name is your project name followed by a long string of garbage.  Under that subfolder, open Build > Products > Debug-iphonesimulator (or Release-iphonesimulator or Debug-iphoneos or whichever you want).

Demo:

[image: finding build product]

Comment: It's easier to open the Products node at the end of the tree in the left side of Xcode and right-click on the app and choose "Show In Finder".

Comment: That only works if you've built for a device target.  If you've only built for a simulator target, that doesn't work.

Comment: unrelated but, how do people create these "gif tutorials"?, i've seen them a lot lately.